# Import a DLRCachedCode class in a IronPython Script

Tags: ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

I'm trying to understand how to import in a IronPython script a dll generated with pyc.py.

Is it possible ? 
Posts all around speak about to use a DLRCachedCode class by C#, instead , I would to import a DLRCachedCode inside an IronPython script.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('foo')
import foo
```

`foo.dll` will have to be in a directory on `sys.path`. If not, you can use `clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath()`.

Comment: This workflow works for clr compiled dll, but not for DLR compiled ones. Infact it fails on import instruction, because no modules are found inside the dll. DLRCachedCode has a different structure respect to classic assemblies.